Geometry Nodes - Move Vertices along their normal

I'm trying to make a geometry nodes set up that moves the vertices along their normal
I've looked at a tutorial and made this, which works on 3d objects but not 2D ones because I think it's moving the faces instead.
Is there a way to move the vertices?
I tried adding an Index and Compare nodes to the Selection input in the Set Position node, which I saw in another question here on how to move the vertices, but they are still moving in the direction of the face normal, not the vertex normal.
Am I missing something?
As far as I know vertices do have a Normal in Blender since you can use it in Edit mode...


The vertices of a flat plane also point upwards. It would be easier if you told us what you need to achieve in order to provide the ideal solution..

@AAAYerus I need them to move along the Red Arrow in the picture

Red arrow doesn't point at normal, it points away from face center. This would be a normal of a 2D curve of the same shape, but not a normal of a vertex belonging to one face, therefore without any interpolation, just copying the face's normal.
